# xts object plot of high frequency data not showing year

Tags: r, datetime, xts

Using the codes  below I make a plot [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAq2O.png) but it does not show year. I am wandering what went wrong. The data is a 5-min intraday data.

```
#load data
aapl<-read.table("AAPL_trades.txt",header=T)
dim(aapl)
head(aapl)
```

#make xts object

```
date<-aapl$Date.Time
date<-as.Date(date)
date<-as.Date(date,"%Y-%m-%d")
AAPL.O<-aapl$AAPL
price<-xts(AAPL.O,date)
head(price)

plot(price,type="l",main="APPLE 5-min intraday price",xlab="Date.Time",ylab="5min price")
```

[5-min intraday plot of AAPL price](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAq2O.png)

```
dput(price)
```

.......
......
......
1106006400, 1106006400, 1106006400, 1106006400, 1106006400, 1106006400, 
1106006400, 1106006400, 1106006400, 1106006400, 1106006400, 1106006400, 
1106006400, 1106006400, 1106006400, 1106006400, 1106006400, 1106006400,
......
.....
.....
1137628800, 1137628800, 1137628800, 1137628800, 1137628800, 1137628800, 
1137628800, 1137628800, 1137628800, 1137628800), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), class = c("xts", 
"zoo"), .indexCLASS = "Date", tclass = "Date", .indexTZ = "UTC", tzone = "UTC")

Comment: It's hard to help without a complete example.  Can you maybe try `dput(aapl)` and include the results in your question so we can tinker with the data?

Comment: Thanks folks, I have done it with ggplot2. I had to sacrifice the time for the year though; it works for me.